# How to get the list of all dictionary values using reflection?

Tags: reflection, dictionary

I have a dictionary and want to get the list of all dictionary values from key/value pairs using reflection. The values can be different types. Keys are strings and I'm able to get all dictionary keys in this way:

```
PropertyInfo p_info_keys = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Keys");
IEnumerable<string> keys = (IEnumerable<string>)p_info_keys.GetValue(obj, null);
```

I can see all dictionary values using this code:

```
PropertyInfo p_info_values = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Values");
object values = p_info_values.GetValue(obj, null);
```

But, I'm not sure how to get something that I can enumerate against instead of object type. So, this line of code is in question:

```
object values = p_info_values.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Any help is appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the weakly typed `IEnumerable` for this job:

```
IEnumerable values = (IEnumerable)p_info_values.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Now you can enumerate the values:

```
foreach(object value in values)
{
    // ...
}
```